# Read file by lines where line separator is a hex number

Tags: python-3.x, hex, readfile, readline

How can I read a file line by line in Python3 but defining as line separator a hexadecimal string?

In Ruby I do it in this way:

```
File.foreach("input.dat", sep="\x17\x05",  encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT') do |line|
    puts line #prints line
end
```

Is there an equivalent or similar way in Python?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Read the whole file and then split by your separator: `for line in open(file).read().split(separator): ...`

Comment: Hi primusa. But doing in that way would have impact in performance if file is big or not?